# Java loop through all strings

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I want to make a program that does something with all strings with a length smaller than a number i want to specify. I'd like something like this:

```
for(int char1 = 32; char1 <= 126; char1++){
  for(int char2 = 32; char2 <= 126; char2++){
    char[] chars = new char[2];
    char[0] = (char)char1; char[1] = (char)char2;
    String s = String.valueOf(chars);
    doStuffWith(s);
  }
}
```

But of course with a selectable ammount of chars. Is this possible?

It's not intended for bruteforcing passwords, but rather to browse through files on a server.

Comment: I'm confused: what kind of "something" is it intended to do?

Comment: It might be about generating a word list for password bruteforcing.

Comment: The simplest solution is using recursion.

Comment: BTW I use a non-ASCII character in my passwords ;)

Comment: Only your imagination sets boundaries :) but to be honest and serious now, if you will explain a little bit more what you want to do, we will probably help.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, you mean the `worst` solution would be using recursion.

Comment: @Johan In that case I would be interested in your solution as I don't like recursion.

Comment: why don't you simply write a clear question, we would help you only if we could understand what you are doing here

Comment: @PeterLawrey, recursion is for complex stuff like quad-trees, not for simple stuff like this.

Comment: Browsing though files on a server works with the `FindFirst` and `FindNext` API call (on Windows anyway).

Comment: @Johan Recursion is still the simplest, fastest and most elegant in this situation.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, simplest-depends on your experience level, fastest-no, elegant-up for discussion. It's really overkill for what's a simple nested loop. (see answer below).

Comment: @Johan Yes, very simple, if you correct all the errors ;) With all the calculations much, much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? A non-recursive solution.

```
int min = 32;
int max = 127;
int numChars = 6; //Set to whatever value you like.
int numDifferentChars = max - min;
int numPossibilities = (int)Math.pow(max - min,numChars);
for(int i = 0;i < numPossibilities;i++) {
    char[] chars = new char[numChars];
    for(int j = 0;j < numChars;j++) {
        int chr = i;
        for(int k = 0;k < j;k++) {
            chr /= numDifferentChars;
        }
        chars[j] = (char)((chr % numDifferentChars) + min);
    }
    doStuffWith(String.valueOf(chars));
}
```

It can be made more efficient I guess, but this seems to work unless numPossibilities has an integer overflow.

EDIT: This code works. I tested it!

Comment: I think you mean `chars[j] = (char)(chr % (max - min + 1) + min);`

Comment: Indeed I did. Well, almost, I changed the "max" in my code to 127 to prevent having all those +1's everywhere.

Comment: The `+ min)` must be inside the brackets.

Comment: And `numDifferentChars = max - min + 1` and `max = 126` as 127 is a delete character.

Answer (score 0):

This compares using loops and recursion.  I don't like recursion in Java in general, but in this case, it is cleaner and faster.

```
private static volatile int dontOptimiseAway;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        long comb = testCombinations(i, 'a', 'z');
        long iter = testIteration(i, 'a', 'z');
        System.out.printf("%d: Comb: %.3f secs, loops: %.3f%n", i, comb / 1e9, iter / 1e9);
    }
}

private static long testCombinations(int maxLetters, char min, char max) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxLetters; i++)
        combinations(i, min, max);
    return System.nanoTime() - start;
}

public static void combinations(int length, char min, char max) {
    combinations0(new char[length], 0, min, max);
}

private static void combinations0(char[] chars, int i, char min, char max) {
    if (i >= chars.length) {
        doStuff(chars);
    } else {
        for (char ch = min; ch <= max; ch++) {
            chars[i] = ch;
            combinations0(chars, i + 1, min, max);
        }
    }

}

private static void doStuff(char[] chars) {
    dontOptimiseAway = chars.length;
}

private static long testIteration(int maxLetters, char min, char max) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxLetters; i++)
        loops(i, min, max);
    return System.nanoTime() - start;
}

public static void loops(int length, char min, char max) {
    int numDifferentChars = max - min + 1;
    long numPossibilities = (long) Math.pow(numDifferentChars, length);
    char[] chars = new char[length];
    for (long i = 0; i < numPossibilities; i++) {
        long chr = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            chars[j] = (char) (chr % numDifferentChars + min);
            chr /= numDifferentChars;
        }
        doStuff(chars);
    }
}
```

prints

```
1: Comb: 0.000 secs, loops: 0.000
2: Comb: 0.000 secs, loops: 0.000
3: Comb: 0.003 secs, loops: 0.004
4: Comb: 0.006 secs, loops: 0.025
5: Comb: 0.116 secs, loops: 0.793
6: Comb: 3.856 secs, loops: 25.101
```